# Pretty Printing with MiniJSON C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using MiniJSON in Unity to serialize.
Want to have good looking JSON, not one-liner.
I know, that JsonUtility allows to make pretty printing, but when I am using it I have empty JSON:

```
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(savePath))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(JsonUtility.ToJson(settings, true));

            }
```

and have this:

```
{}
```

Code has been used with MiniJSON is:

```
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(savePath))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(MiniJSON.Json.Serialize(settings));

            }
```

and the result is a normal one-liner JSON.
Can I use Pretty printing with MiniJSON and how?